# How to make the touch pad normal/minimal in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, touchpad, mouse-gestures

I have bought a ASUS Vivobook S510U and installed linux Mint.
The mouse is behaving abnormally.

For example, it simulates the middle/scroll key of the mouse when I click in the middle of the right and left click button. However, this simulation often closes a window. I have accidentally closed many windows so far. Which is problematic.

Sometimes, the mouse button randomly pastes different info that I have typed early or which is from another window. Sometimes, it cuts different texts as well for which I have to press ctrl+z again and again.

I think the OS as well as the mouse pad is trying to emulate gesture based features. But I want a normal old school touchpad with right/left click, two finger scroll only.

I have looked into 'Muse and Touchpad' section of the settings and seen that the click action is set to 'Automatic'. I have changed them to other settings, but they do not seem to ideal to me.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window and type in `xinput list`. It should show you a list of input devices, including your keyboard and touchpad. Note the `id=N` number of the touchpad device.

Then type `xinput --list-props N` where N is the ID number of your touchpad device. It should display all the settable properties your touchpad hardware and its driver provides. With the `xinput --set-prop N <property> <value>` you can manipulate those settings even if the settings GUI does not visualize them.

If you find a series of settings that makes the touchpad behave the way you want, you could write the necessary commands into a script, and place that file into `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` directory, or use some other way to automatically run that script whenever you log in (depends on your desktop environment of choice).